# Global Platform CRS application activate card issue

Tags: nfc, javacard, apdu, globalplatform

I am trying to activate a card using CRS applet of GP

> The full Command APDU passed was 80F001010A4F08XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00   (
>   when group by bytes CLA::80 INS::F0 P1::01 P2::01 Lc::0A TAG::4F L::08
>   V::AID::XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 11 Le::00)

XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX is the AID place holder .

The CRS is present and I am able to get the global counter too.

But when I try above Command to activate I am getting **6D 00** ( which interprets to “Invalid Instruction”), but for my best knowledge the command APDU  is well formed according to GP spec.

Comment: Uh, wow, that's a very specific question. I'm not sure there will be many people that are used to this kind of Global Platform functionality about Contactless Registry Services. I'm not even sure if this request for clarification is even applicable, but did you go through some kind of authentication procedure before issuing the command?

Comment: You must be more specific about the context in which you are doing this : in an OTA message, on the ISO interface (through a logical channel) directly ?